# How Vector synchronized and Vector increases its size by doubling the array size

Tags: java, vector, synchronization, size

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Simple {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vector v1 = new Vector();
        v1.add(5);
        v1.add(6);
        v1.add(9);
        v1.add(4);
        v1.add(1);

        Iterator it = v1.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }
}
```

when i run this Program then Output come

5
6
9
4
1
 so i am bit confused about its definition that :

1.Vector is synchronized.
2.Vector increases its size by doubling the array size

please explain .

Comment: What is the issue with the out put? what is your expected out put for this?

Comment: it doesn't actually doubles the array size. But creates a new array of double the size and copy the contents from old array into the new one. The old array is left abandoned and will be garbage collected.

Comment: Side note: Vector is obsolete and you should use an ArrayList as a  replacement in most situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Vector is synchronized.

That means the vector methods are synchronized by default so the operations on vector are thread-safe.

```
2.Vector increases its size by doubling the array size
```

The initial capacity of vector is 10. When the size of vector reaches 10 then it doubles it's capacity. so if the size is 10 then the capacity will be 20

Comment: Not exactly, as I said in my answer - the capacity is doubled a bit earlier.

Comment: can u please add some code for checking which vector method Synchronized   you Mean to say that add()  ? can u please tell me how to check using code?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Vector.java#Vector.add%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: How internal array is re-sized depends on the implementation. It may vary from OpenJDK to Oracle's JDK.

Comment: yes scardge and arora is right .. i just wanted to describe it as what it does instead of how it does

Answer (score 0):

1. To check if Vector is synchronized (which it is..), you have to use multiple threads and try writing to the vector.. You are not doing it..
2. yes, internally vector is designed to do so.. yet if you do vector.size() it shows you the number of elements currently in the vector (not the actual size allocated).  look at the source code of vector to understand how size change is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

1. Vector is synchronized means that if you do some operations (e.g. add an element) from different threads, you won't get unexpected results, which means that each operation will be done correctly.
2. When you create a vector with `new Vector()` it's inner array is initialized with some size, so it can contain only a certain number of values. But when you try to add a value, when more than a half of its inner array is filled, the inner array is reinitialized with a doubled size, so that you can contain as much values, as you need.